# Can't create Microsoft 365 Development Program (phone number already in use.)

Tags: sandbox, dynamics-365, ie-developer-tools

I'm facing some problems when creating a new Microsoft 365 Development Program account when i try requesting the SMS verification code. I get:

We can't continue with the signup process for the following reason:

Your phone number is already associated with an existing developer account.
For help with your Microsoft account, go to Microsoft account and verify your information.

MS-CorrelationID: f21a28b2-4534-4bb9-8167-1323c8b2d00e

Code: 40901

The problem is that i had an dev account set up before on my previous job, but  I no longer work there so I dont have access to that email.

Please help:)

tried logging in with email accounts by the login is registration on my previous email

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I feel that only Microsoft can help you with this.  I'd contact their support.